# getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms keeps on showing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I tried searching for an answer for quite long and can't find a solution to this problem. I released my App not too long ago in the Play Store, the Authentication for firebase and Realtime Database is working fine in the release version.

However, I wanted to modify some of the code and update it in the google play store. Thus, I changed the code in my Android Studio and the Authentication is not working anymore. This error keeps popping up.

```
01-29 23:58:28.578 22699-22725/com.name.package W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
01-29 23:58:29.745 22699-22725/com.name.package W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
```

here is my Gradle File

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.wdullaer:MaterialDateTimePicker:v3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.dmallcott:DismissibleImageView:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I tried all of the relevant StackOverflow topics but none of the solutions worked for me. I checked all the SHA certificates. All are alright with no problems at all. Can someone help me solve this problem? I can't seem to connect with the debug version, but my release version is working fine.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but you should be using [firebase-ui-database:3.2.1](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) or 3.1.3 with Firebase SDK 11.8.0.

Comment: Alright! will change my dependencies! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Note that the "error" message in your post is just a warning.  I don't think it is an indication of a problem that prevents auth from working.  I see the message in an app where auth is working without error.  Also check that the device(s) you are testing on have a version of Google Play services that is compatible with Firebase 11.8.0.  Look in the logcat at the time the app initializes for this warning: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.

Comment: yep even though it is a warning, it keeps repeating several times and it doesn't allow me to connect to the Firebase's Authentication server. I'll try looking out for the warning you mentioned and update ASAP.